# How to do algorithm visualization?

Tags: algorithm, unit-testing, visualization

I am looking for an algorithm visualization library/tool that is well documented and you can call from your source code.
I took a look at [jhave](http://www.jhave.org) -  [example of usage](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gudGmmBFFGw). And I liked it, it seems it has some documentation but I do not trust its future.
I found this article about [Algorithm explorer](http://unt.academia.edu/IanParberry/Papers/210273/Algorithm_Explorer_Visualizing_Algorithms_In_a_3D_Multimedia_Environment) it has a nice idea. It is implemented as a c++ api but I cannot find it anywere.

My main idea is that I want to do some unit tests for the brain. 
So I construct various exercises and in future when I want to test my knowledge I redo them.
I found that images stick longer with me, so that is why I want to visualize algorithms in certain states. ( I might remember better a tricky case like what happens when data is sorted in reverse and I use quick sort if I view it.)

An ideal tool:
1. Has to integrate with any language.
2. Has to be well documented with a growing comunity and examples. 
3. Be implemented on top of a capable rendering engine(ogre, xna).

Comment: "Has to integrate with *any* language" is a probably too strict requirement. Except if you are willing to write some bindings yourself.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines: You call makeRectangle(number) this sends, over AF_INET sockets, info to a server that renders a rectangle with a number in it.

Comment: Your requirement 3 is maybe misleading. A good tool would be independent from any rendering engine, it's output limited to some standard visualization *format*, not *engine*.
@phimuemue: I think the requirement is not about the language in which the tool is programmed with, but the language of the algorithm.

Comment: Take a look at Bret Victor's article http://worrydream.com/#!/LadderOfAbstraction
By the way, a good tool for testing programming ideas is Processing (http://processing.org/)

Comment: Why not visualize finite state automata? I believe there are theorems stating which algorithms can be represented by FSA's and which one's can't. The big benefit of FSA is that you can easily represent them with graphs using graphviz:
http://www.graphviz.org/  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: You might also like *this* Bret Victor video: http://vimeo.com/36579366

Answer (score 2):

Here is the place you need to visit: [The Algorithm Visualization Portal](http://algoviz.org/)!

Comment: That is a great link, I have been staring at code for k-d tree stuff all week and I didn't realize how instructive it'd be to see it in action, as it were. Salud.